# I am learning C++ via a book. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: c++, hyperlink

I am learning C++ via a book. It told me to type this compile and link it in order for me to see if i can read it. But there are errors when I run this. What is the issue?

```
#include <iostream>  
int main()  
{   
int x = 8;      
int y = 6;      
std::cout << std::end1;     
std::cout << x - y << " " << x * y << " " << x + y;     
std::cout << std::end1;     return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Without the error, it's kinda hard. But you wrote `std::end1` where it should be `std::endl`, the last character being l instead of 1.

Comment: What is your error? Could you please show us the command you use to compile?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is *assuming that your error message is irrelevant*.  It's telling you *what* and *where* the problem is.

Comment: The error is the `end1`, which should be `endl`.

Answer (score 5):

It should be `std::endl;` instead of `std::end1;`

Comment: Thank You so much!!! This book is making me worry if I should keep using it. Every time they type 1 it's either a "I' or "l" lol

Comment: Consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list